# Webservice Exception Javascript DWR

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, soap, dwr

I'm trying to unravel a Webservice work and replicating it's call, but I've been unable to do it.

In [this](http://soap.pentasecurity.cl/Soap2014Web/Poliza.do?idSponsor=OTY2ODMxMjA=#) website, if you input, for example, `HY6210` a new window appears with data already filled in.
Using Firebug I was able to determine it was calling
[this link](http://soap.pentasecurity.cl/Soap2014Web/dwr/call/plaincall/ventaVehiculo.buscarVehiculoDWR.dwr),
but no matter what I do in terms of parameters, headers, and cookies, I always get either:

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#DWR-REPLY
if (window.dwr) dwr.engine._remoteHandleBatchException({ name:'java.lang.SecurityException',         message:'Call IDs may only contain Java Identifiers' });
else if (window.parent.dwr) window.parent.dwr.engine._remoteHandleBatchException({  name:'java.lang.SecurityException', message:'Call IDs may only contain Java Identifiers' });
```

or

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#DWR-REPLY
if (window.dwr) dwr.engine._remoteHandleBatchException({name:'org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerException',    message:'The specified call count is not a number'    });
else if (window.parent.dwr) window.parent.dwr.engine._remoteHandleBatchException({ name:'org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerException', message:'The specified call count is not a number' });
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, historyTracking is the class name and `getStoppageV3` method then you pass `device1` variable in JavaScript and then you forcefully convert this variabal in string then you use `device1.toString()`.

Example:

```
historyTracking.getStoppageV3(device1.toString()
```